# How to maintain relation between MySQL tables downloaded via SQOOP to Hive

Tags: mysql, sqoop

I have an ETL pipeline that downloads multiple tables from MysqlRDS and runs hive ETL's on the top of this data. But I noticed an issue with the downloaded data. As the tables are being downloaded individually the relation between the tables was not being maintained. Is there a feature in SQOOP that allows the relationship between multiple tables to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the data lineage using Apache Atlas.